# Twitter button causes text-align:center not to work

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

I'm trying to add a twitter "follow" button to the footer on my site, but it is causing numerous problems with the display of the footer.

If you take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BcuRQ/2), you can see the issues. I've added testing controls to make it easier to demonstrate, but basically, I want to stop the following things from happening when the button is added:

- Extra padding at the top
- Everything being moved to the left (losing `text-align:center`)
- The button not being vertically aligned with the text to the left of it.

Please can someone advise on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter button gets styled through javascript to a width of 300px, only thing getting around that is to wrap it up with a span or a div and put it on a width of 60px; Because 300px pushes you menu to the side. Losing your text align center.

Also you might want to wrap your links in a unordered list element so you have more control over the whole group and it becomes more semantic.

[My solution](http://jsfiddle.net/BcuRQ/5/)